# Nested class template full specialization versus partial specialization

Tags: c++, template-specialization, nested-class

The following code is giving me the compile error:

> error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct Apply'
>         template < >
>
> ```
>             ^
> ```

```
#include <iostream>

struct Apply
{
    template < typename ...BaseClasses>
    struct Inheritance;

    template < typename FirstBaseClass, typename ...OtherBaseClasses>
    struct Inheritance< FirstBaseClass, OtherBaseClasses... >   : FirstBaseClass
            , Inheritance< OtherBaseClasses... >
    {

    };

    template < >
    struct Inheritance< >
    {

    };
};

struct A{ int a; };
struct B{ int b; };
struct C{ int c; };

struct Example : Apply::Inheritance< A, B, C >
{
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Example ex;

    ex.print();

    return 0;
}
```

In another post I read that the problem is the just the **full template specialization**, and that with a **partial template specialization** I would be able to fix this. But how can I change the inheritance recursion in my code to achieve this? I tried but I only broke it badly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have to simply move it outwards.

```
template < >
struct Apply::Inheritance< >
{

};
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying everything but the simplest thing!